# Forward Windows port to WSL2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a use case where I develop both on Windows and on WSL2, and need make it possible for a .NET application to be served on Windows on port 44301, and be accessible from within WSL2 (Ubuntu) on localhost:44301.

I am aware that there is an IP for the Windows host machine that is accessible from within WSL2 (and this can be discovered with `grep -m 1 nameserver /etc/resolv.conf | awk '{print $2}'`) but that is not what I am trying to achieve. What I would like to do is to forward the 44301 port on windows to localhost:44301 on WSL2

Comment: You need to think in terms of the actual connection, i.e. if the client is on WSL2 and connects to localhost:44301, then you'll want to forward the WSL2 port to the Windows host's port where the server-side of the application is, not vice versa.

Comment: You need the good old rinetd, I think. (`sudo apt get install rinetd` on the wsl2 command line. Then edit the rinetd.conf, start, enjoy.

Comment: I've done this before using `netsh portproxy`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-interface-portproxy

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about WSL2, but on a real Linux you might do something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVERIP=$(grep -m 1 nameserver /etc/resolv.conf | awk '{print $2}')

# Turn on the IPv4 packet forwarding master switch
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

# Change the destination of TCP packets arriving to loopback interface's
# port 44301 to the same port on the actual Windows server
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i lo -p tcp --dport 44301 -j DNAT --to-destination $SERVERIP

# Allow the forwarding of any existing forwarded connections
# (to ensure replies from the Windows server are also allowed)
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow the forwarding of connections arriving to loopback TCP port 44301
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -p tcp -i lo --dport 44301 -j ACCEPT
```